# How do we solve for $n$?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, computational-complexity

Asymptotic complexity gives an idea of how rapidly the space/time
requirements grow as problem size increases.

• Suppose we have a computing device that can execute 1000 complex
operations per second.

Here is the size problem that can be solved in
a second, a minute, and an hour by algorithms of different asymptotic
complexity:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Complexity} & 1 \text{second} & 1 \text{minute} & 1 \text{hour}\\ 
- & - & - & -\\ 
n & 1000 & 60.000 & 3.600.000 \\ \\
n\log n & 140 & 4893 & 200.000 \\ \\
n^2 & 31 & 244 & 1897 
\end{matrix}$$

Could you explain me how we found the following?
 $$n \log n=1000 \Rightarrow n=140$$

Comment: This is probably not as trivial as you'd like. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847327/how-to-calculate-n-log-n-c).

Comment: Since we're not after an _exact_ answer, some manner of intelligent trial-and-error (e.g. Newton's method) is probably the best way.

Comment: @Arthur The Newton's method is the following: 

$$n_{i+1}=n_i-\frac{f(n_i)}{f'(n_i)}$$ 

Do we have to replace $f(n_i)$ with $1000$ ? Or how can we find an approxiomation of the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The number 140 comes from $1000/\ln 1000 \approx 1000/6.91 \approx 144$ which was then rounded.

If you can do $n= 1000$ operations in 1, then for an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm, you need to do $1000 \log 1000$ operations to accomplish the same task, so it takes $\log 1000$ times longer than the $O(n)$ algorithm, so the size of problem that you can solve is a factor of $\log 1000$ times smaller. The logarithm used appears to be the natural logarithm in this case for the numbers to work out.

Comment: We have $f(n)=n \log_2{n}$ and, taking into consideration that the algorithm that solves the problem requires time $f(n)$ microseconds(1 microsecond=$10^{-6}$ second), we want to find the maximum size $n$ of the problem that can be solved in time $t$, where $t$ is one century.
$$$$
Is the desired result: 100*365*24*3600*10^6/log_2(100*365*24*3600*10^6) ?
$$$$